# Downloading the HTML from another resource and not using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I created the following file inside the `spiders` directory of the scrapy project. The problem that I am facing is that the function inside `middlewares.py` namely `process_request` and `process_response` are not called. What could be the reason for this?

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://liv.ai/'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url,"...", response.status)
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

I want to have download the HTML from the webpage using another process and not scrapy. That is the reason, I want to listen in the middleware and direct to another source that could download the HTML and send back the response.

Comment: How do you find out that they are not called and why do you want them called?
BTW, this is not a nice architecture. You should not store the remote response in the local file anywhere in your spider. This is why we have pipelines. Parse the data, yield it, Scrapy will pass it to the pipelines. Then write your own custom pipeline which would store the response in a file.
Please note that in order to trigger the pipelines, uou must ```yield``` something inside your ```parse``` method. Currently, you are yielding ```None```.

Comment: Before you start using something like Splash or Selenium, make sure you read https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Target website uses js/ajax for creating the beautiful layout that you see in your browser whereas your crawler see *something else*; your approach seems fine for regular websites however with this specific website, you will never get all the html code without using a headless browser - try **selenium** or **splash** in order to view processed html.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem that I am facing is that the function inside middlewares.py namely process_request and process_response are not called. What could be the reason for this?

Since you do not mention it explicitly, you might have forgotten to [enable the middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#activating-a-spider-middleware). Defining it in a `middlewares.py` is not enough (or necessary, middlewares can be defined in many different places).